# Add accountStatus to new users on app startup

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to add `accountStatus` to the users I create when I first run the application however it keeps crashing. `accountStatus` is not part of `user.profile`.

Can someone please look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Path: `server.js`

```
// run at Meteor app startup
Meteor.startup(function(options, user) {

  // if users database is empty, seed these values
  if(Meteor.users.find().count() < 1) {

    // users array
    var users = [
      {firstName: 'Sam', lastName: 'Smith', email: 'sam@gmail.com', roles: ['is_student']},   
    ];
    // user creation
    _.each(users, function(userData) {
      // return id for use in roles assignment below
      var userId = Accounts.createUser({
        email: userData.email,
        password: 'password',
        profile: {
          firstName: userData.firstName,
          lastName: userData.lastName,
        }
      });
      // verify user email
      Meteor.users.update({ _id: userId }, { $set: { 'emails.0.verified': true } });
      // add roles to user
      Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, userData.roles);

      // add accountStatus and set to true
      _.extend(userId, { accountStatus: true });

    });
    console.log('New users created!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
_.extend(userId, { accountStatus: true });
```

And look at [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) definition:

> Copy all of the properties in the source objects over to the destination object, and return the destination object. It's in-order, so the last source will override properties of the same name in previous arguments.

What this line is supposed to do?

Comment: I was hoping this line would add accountStatus = true to the users account.

Comment: So do an update - just like you do five lines higher: `Meteor.users.update({ _id: userId }, { $set: { accountStatus: true } });`

Comment: I must have had a typo when I tried that last time because your solution works. Thanks @Radoslaw